# Derive upper bound for inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and a random variable $Z$ also taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose $\sup_z \lvert f(z)\rvert = B <\infty$
Consider the following vectors $S = (Z_1,..,Z_n)$ and $S'= (Z_1,...,Z_i',..,Z_n)$, so you only change the i-th component for a given sample. Each $Z_i$ is a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then I want to show that:

$$|g(S)-g(S')| \leq \frac{2B}{n}$$

for $$g(S):= \left\lvert \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(Z_i)- E[f(Z)]\right\rvert $$

If I didn't have  $E[f(Z)]$ I would get: $|g(S)-g(S')| =  |\frac{1}{n} \left( f(Z_i) -  f(Z_i')\right) | \leq  \frac{1}{n} 2B $.

What can I do with $E[f(Z)]$
Are they the same if I only change the $i$-th component?

Comment: Something is inconsistent in the notation here. Do you mean that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Z_i$ are components of $Z$ or should we think of $S$ being $n^2$ long (or equivalently that $S$ is a $n \times n$ matrix)?

Comment: Yes $Z_i$ are the components of Z.

Comment: So $f$ is not from $\mathbb{R}^n$ but $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes sorry. That is also true

Comment: @Lundborg: I edited my question. Each random variable is in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The vector is a collection of these simulating a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that by the reversed triangular inequality,
$$
\left\lvert g(S)-g(S')\right\rvert=
\left\lvert \left\lvert \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(Z_j)- E[f(Z)]\right\rvert -\left\lvert   \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(Z^*_j)- E[f(Z)]\right\rvert \right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(Z_j)- E[f(Z)] -    \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n f(Z^*_j)- E[f(Z)] \right) \right\rvert,
$$
where $Z_j^*=Z_j$ if $j\neq i$ and $Z_i^*=Z'_i$. So the term $E[f(Z)]$ will cancel out.

Comment: Thank you. It holds  $|1/n(f(Z_j) - f(Z^*_j)) \leq 1/n ( |f(Z^*_j) |+ f|(Z^*_j)|) \leq 1/n 2B$ isn't it?

Comment: Actually, $j$ is the index of summation, so the remaining term is the one for index $i$. Then it is more accurate to use $\lvert a-b\rvert\leqslant \lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert$ than $\lvert a-b\rvert\leqslant\lvert a+b\rvert$, since this inequality may not hold if $a=-b$.

Comment: I see thank you:)

Comment: You are welcome!